# I have a Dual G5 Power Mac I can only start in safe mode

Tags: startup, powerpc, g5

Processor: Dual 2 GHz PowerPC G5
Memory: 1.5 GB DDR SDRAM

I can only start with a safe boot.

I've used the Leopard disk to run Disk Utility to repair the disks. There appears to be no problems. Verify disks returns no errors and a repair disks also finished with no errors.

I'm stuck for ideas...

Comment: What happens when you don't start in safe mode?

Comment: I get the black screen (with power button icon) which says I have to restart.

Comment: On the console it says can't open input server /library/ input managers/ ctloader

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you have described, it appears that there is an issue occurring with a kernel extension, driver, or something along those lines.  This is what is causing your machine to kernel panic when attempting to boot up normally. Safe mode is disabling the problematic "thing" and that is why you machine boots fine in safe mode. For more information on whats is going on when you boot in safe mode see [Mac OS X: What is Safe Boot, Safe Mode?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564), this may be valuable in diagnosing a cause of the kernel panic on start-up.

So some next steps for you to take:

First thing is figure out what is causing the kernel panic. Boot into safe mode and then open the Console program. Located at /Applications/Utilities/Console

When in the Console application look for the logs noted as PanicReporter, if we are lucky there should be one for each time you tried to boot the machine with a failed boot up. According to [Mac OS X: How to log a kernel panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2546), kernel panic logs for Leopard are stored in /Library/Logs/PanicReporter, so check for logs at that path in console.

If you find logs do a quick read thru of of the first 20 or so lines and see if you recognize the name for a piece of hardware /software or something, feel free to post what you find as well to help in solving the problem.

Once you have figured out what driver/s or extension/s is causing the problem the next step is to determine if it is a driver that you installed. If it is then look up how to remove and additionally re-install it or update it if it is something you need.

If its a driver for something else built into the computer it could be indicating a hard ware failure for some kind of device, eg network card, etc. Or it could be just a corrupted software driver, and you may need to backup your date and re install the Mac OS.

Comment: I couldn't open the panic reports the console just froze. I tried to repair permissions and this froze too. However when I restarted the computer I got the chime and a successful start up. So, I'm still at a loss as to what is wrong but I'll probably do a back up and re-install. I think it's time to get a new computer though.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a Mac OS CD/DVD and try performing a "Verify Disk" and "Repair Permissions" on your G5's normal start-up disk.

Comment: Yes, I did both verify and repair disk. Everything was okay here. I also tried to verify permissions and to repair permissions. On both occassions the process froze. After the 'verify permissions' failure/freeze I needed to safe boot the system. However after the 'repair permissions' failure/freeze I got the start up tone and managed to restart as normal. So I think the problem is maybe with the permissions. The computer is left running at the moment. I think a back up and clean install will fix this.

Comment: Ya Back up and re-install sounds like a good plan. I would watch the drive too it may be preparing to fail, if your new install starts to go bad quickly, it may be that the drive is starting to fail by corrupting random data...